# Gradle plugin dont meet kotlin version

Tags: flutter, gradle

[image]

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.

The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using an older version of the `location` package, which uses kotlin 1.4.20. Try updating the `location` package to one of the more recent versions, run `flutter pub get` and try rerunning the project.